# Multi-language site - one domain or multiple domains?

Tags: seo, multilingual

Which one is the best way to contruct a multi-language site if you want the most effective SEO?

Use a single domain?

```
www.domain.com/en
www.domain.com/de
www.domain.com/dk
```

Or use multiple domains, one for each language?

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.de
www.domain.dk
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have multi-lingual content you should follow [Google's new multi-lingual guidelines](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html). Basically, you use subdomains for the different translations:

> To explain how it works, let’s look at some example URLs:
>   http://www.example.com/ - contains the general homepage of a website, in Spanish
>   http://es-es.example.com/ - is the version for users in Spain, in Spanish
>   http://es-mx.example.com/ - is the version for users in Mexico, in Spanish
>   http://en.example.com/ - is the generic English language version
>   On all of these pages, we could use the following markup to specify language and optionally the region:
>
> ```
> <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/" />
> <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-ES" href="http://es-es.example.com/" />
> <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-MX" href="http://es-mx.example.com/" />
> <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.example.com/" />
> ```
>
> If you specify a regional subtag, we’ll assume that you want to target that region.
>   Keep in mind that all of these annotations are to be used on a per-URL basis. You should take care to use the specific URL, not the homepage, for both of these link elements.

Comment: Yes, that is where they belong

Comment: I think you got it wrong, you don't have to use subdomains. You can use these two attributes for links like <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-ES" href="http://example.com/en-es" />
You have still the choice to use subdomains, subdirectories, etc.
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192&topic=2370587&ctx=topic

Comment: So having specific domains is allowed then.